# Error in check out svn repository

Tags: svn

Im new in using SVN. So please, When i try to Check out the wikipedia miner trunk with svn, i get the following error: 
svn: Repository moved permenatly to 'svnroot/wikipedia-miner/trunk%20wikipedia-miner';please relocate svn:OPTIONSrequest failed on'/svnroot/svnroot/wikipedia-miner/trunk%20wikipedia-miner'. Any help please? what is the problem?

In the New Repository Location i typed the following URL:

https://wikipedia-miner.svn.sourceforge.net/svnroot/wikipedia-miner/trunk wikipedia-miner

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With this repository location, I can able to get the repo information & checkout also works fine.

```
jayaprakash@cloudenablers:/tmp$ svn info  https://svn.code.sf.net/p/wikipedia-miner/code/trunk
Path: trunk
URL: https://svn.code.sf.net/p/wikipedia-miner/code/trunk
Relative URL: ^/trunk
Repository Root: https://svn.code.sf.net/p/wikipedia-miner/code
Repository UUID: 166c8578-5d49-0410-b467-b9387edea209
Revision: 236
Node Kind: directory
Last Changed Author: d_milne
Last Changed Rev: 236
Last Changed Date: 2012-04-02 02:45:30 +0530 (Mon, 02 Apr 2012)

jayaprakash@cloudenablers:/tmp$ svn co  https://svn.code.sf.net/p/wikipedia-miner/code/trunk
A    trunk/test
A    trunk/test/org
A    trunk/test/org/wikipedia
A    trunk/test/org/wikipedia/miner
A    trunk/test/org/wikipedia/miner/db
......
......
A    trunk/examples/ComparingWikisaurus.java
A    trunk/examples/Wikisaurus.java
A    trunk/examples/SnippetAnnotator.java
A    trunk/examples/AnnotationWorkbench.java
Checked out revision 236.
jayaprakash@cloudenablers:/tmp$
```